# List available methods of encryption for LUKS

Tags: encryption

I was searching for a valid and still up-to-date way of encrypting hard disks. After some research I encountered *LUKS* and decided to give it a shot. So I looked up some examples of how to properly encrypt an HDD with it, like this:

`cryptsetup --verbose --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 5000 --use-random luksFormat /dev/sda3`

The *--cipher* and *--hash* part of it was most interesting for me, so I tried to inform myself regarding different ciphers and hashes that are specifically usable for LUKS. I couldn't find any useful information besides opening a file which shows the available encryption forms in a machine-friendly formatting for the currently used Linux. But as I was told even this file is probably missing the full extent of all encryption ways besides it being very hard to read for someone who doesn't deal with it on a daily basis, anyway.

My question: is there a **full** list of ciphers/hashes for LUKS encryption?

One that simply shows me what I can choose... 
and maybe gives a short description on what exactly the differences between those different ways are.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using and configuring LUKS and the Linux kernel, not about the cryptography that these tools use. It would be on-topic on [unix.se]. I've flagged this question for migration, please do not repost unless it gets closed without migration.

Comment: I specifically chose the Cryptography area, because my question is directed towarda ciphers and hashes. I took the "tour" for this area and it literally has it in the "Questions you should ask:" slot. Look it up, if you want.

Comment: That's why I didn't put the question in Unix & Linux because it would be off-topic there....

Comment: *gives a short description on what exactly the differences between those different ways are* This is the only part of your question that is on-topic. What's the main difference between AES and Twofish? Well, AES uses a substitution permutation network while Twofish uses a Feistel network. Based on this information, you should clearly select AES because there is nothing wrong with a Feistel network in principle.

Answer (score 12):

That's basically up to your kernel, so "**See /proc/crypto**" is supposed to be "the answer." The cryptsetup man page says this:

```
NOTES ON SUPPORTED CIPHERS, MODES, HASHES AND KEY SIZES

   The available combinations of ciphers, modes, hashes and key  sizes  depend
   on  kernel  support.  See /proc/crypto for a list of available options. You
   might need to load additional kernel crypto modules in order  to  get  more
   options.

   For  the  --hash option, if the crypto backend is libgcrypt, then all algo‐
   rithms supported by the gcrypt library are  available.   For  other  crypto
   backends some algorithms may be missing.
```

However, my `/proc/crypto` doesn't mention any serpent, or xts(aes), so instead I'd recommend seeing what `cryptsetup benchmark` reports (and it would show (ram) speeds too). For example:

```
$ cryptsetup benchmark
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1       292752 iterations per second
PBKDF2-sha256     221362 iterations per second
PBKDF2-sha512     142010 iterations per second
PBKDF2-ripemd160  277124 iterations per second
PBKDF2-whirlpool  155727 iterations per second
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b   164.7 MiB/s   164.5 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b   119.5 MiB/s   205.0 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b   163.5 MiB/s   208.6 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b   148.4 MiB/s   147.9 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   256b   128.1 MiB/s   205.3 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   256b   202.3 MiB/s   213.1 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b   165.4 MiB/s   145.3 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   256b   150.0 MiB/s   194.5 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   256b   206.4 MiB/s   206.9 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b   149.4 MiB/s   147.5 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   512b   181.7 MiB/s   195.0 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   512b   207.1 MiB/s   208.6 MiB/s
```

The hashes are the first few lines (sha1, sha256, sha512, ripemd160, whirlpool). Ciphers are under the Algorithm header.

Looking at what the defaults are gives a good idea of what's considered "pretty good" too:

```
$ cryptsetup --help|tail -n 8
Default compiled-in key and passphrase parameters:
    Maximum keyfile size: 8192kB, Maximum interactive passphrase length 512 (characters)
Default PBKDF2 iteration time for LUKS: 1000 (ms)

Default compiled-in device cipher parameters:
    loop-AES: aes, Key 256 bits
    plain: aes-cbc-essiv:sha256, Key: 256 bits, Password hashing: ripemd160
    LUKS1: aes-xts-plain64, Key: 256 bits, LUKS header hashing: sha1, RNG: /dev/urandom
```

And using a higher key size (with `--key-size`) should only be stronger, if slightly slower.

```
   --key-size, -s <bits>
          Sets  key  size in bits. The argument has to be a multiple of 8.
          The possible key-sizes are limited by the cipher and mode used.

          See /proc/crypto for more information.  Note  that  key-size  in
          /proc/crypto is stated in bytes.
```

Comment: That's exactly what I complained about... /proc/crypto is highly unreadable and therefore useless. Some ciphers are even twice in the list and I don't know why.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure, wasn't in the question, but that's definitely a concern, even a web search about /proc/crypto doesn't reveal any obvious guides. I'm noticing some differences, and I think cryptsetup uses block ciphers only, for encrypting disk blocks, so the 'type: blkcipher' ones seem logical. But I'm also noticing mine doesn't mention any serpent, or xts-aes... but I've got another idea that might be better, I'll edit it into the answer

Answer (score 5):

in reference to the work of user notdavidcronenberg: The only answer I found is in the document [LUKS On-Disk Format Specification](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/LUKS-standard/on-disk-format.pdf) (PDF).

> #### Valid cipher names
>
> - `aes` Advanced Encryption Standard - FIPS PUB 197
> - `twofish` Twofish: A 128-Bit Block Cipher - https://www.schneier.com/paper-twofish-paper.html
> - `serpent` https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/serpent.html
> - `cast5` RFC 2144
> - `cast6` RFC 2612
>
> #### Valid cipher modes
>
> - `ecb` The cipher output is used directly.
> - `cbc-plain` The cipher is operated in CBC mode. The CBC chaining is cut every sector, and reinitialised with the sector number as
>     initial vector (converted to 32-bit and to little-endian). This mode
>     is specified in [Fru05b], Chapter 4.
> - `cbc-essiv:{hash}` The cipher is operated in ESSIV mode using hash for  generating the IV key for the original key. For instance, when
>     using sha256 as hash, the cipher mode spec is “cbcessiv:sha256”. ESSIV
>     is specified in [Fru05b], Chapter 4.
> - `xts-plain64` plain64 is 64-bit version of plain initial vector
>
> #### Valid hash specifications
>
> - `sha1` RFC 3174 - US Secure Hash Algorithm 1 (SHA1)
> - `sha256` SHA variant according to FIPS 180-2
> - `sha512` SHA variant according to FIPS 180-2
> - `ripemd160` http://www.esat.kuleuven.ac.be/~bosselae/ripemd160.html

Comment: the list is not complete https://superuser.com/a/1450671/446140